# Inserting attribute in XMLnode using javascript xml parser

Tags: javascript, xml

This is the xml string stored in a variable "xml".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn:definitions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:extratask="http://extratask" id="Definitions_1" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn">
<bpmn:process id="Process_1" isExecutable="false">
  <bpmn:task id="Task_15xgmrn" name="Select1Select5" extratask:entity="Select1" extratask:action="Select5" />
<bpmn:task id="Task_0ditp3t" name="Select2Select6" extratask:entity="Select2" extratask:action="Select6" />
<bpmn:task id="Task_0p68hrl" name="Select3Select6" extratask:entity="Select3" extratask:action="Select6" />
</bpmn:process>
</bpmn:definitions>
```

So far, I have just tried to read the nodes "bpmn:task" into console with this code but getting blank array.

```
if(window.DOMParser){
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
}else{
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
}
console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("bpmn:task"));
```

please someone make me understand that where I am going wrong, and another thing is that I want to insert some attributes into "bpmn:task" tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute `xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"` denotes a custom namespace for your XML, which means you have to use [`getElementsByTagNameNS()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagNameNS) with the give namespace to get the tags

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL","task")
```

```js
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><bpmn:definitions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:extratask="http://extratask" id="Definitions_1" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn"><bpmn:process id="Process_1" isExecutable="false"><bpmn:task id="Task_15xgmrn" name="Select1Select5" extratask:entity="Select1" extratask:action="Select5" /><bpmn:task id="Task_0ditp3t" name="Select2Select6" extratask:entity="Select2" extratask:action="Select6" /><bpmn:task id="Task_0p68hrl" name="Select3Select6" extratask:entity="Select3" extratask:action="Select6" /></bpmn:process></bpmn:definitions>';

var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");

console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL","task"));
```

Comment: The suggestion to use `getElementsByTagNameNS` is fine but you should then remove the `else` branch` as MSXML does not support that DOM Level 2 method at all.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - good point, and DOMParser is supported from IE9 and up anyway, so the old MSXML parser shouldn't be needed anyyway.